# dropdown panel with java

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I am currently working to create a GUI and encountered the following problem:
Similar to a JComboBox or JMenu i want to create a drop-down-panel with java, but i don't want to list a few JMenuItems or something similar. What I want to display is a new JPanel. You could compare it to the chatwindow in facebook.

Not eve Google could help me. All I could find was about JComboBox or JMenu.

So here is my question: Is there already a predefined class, that im just unable to find or do I have to make one for myself? If I have to create it, how do I do it?

Comment: See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/PopupFactory.html). Simply create a new popup and fill it with your component.

Comment: You can actually add any Component to a JMenu.  You are not restricted to only JMenuItems.

Comment: @VGR You, sir, have taught me something today. Kudos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring this to an "official" end:

You can actually add any Component to a JMenu. You are not restricted to only JMenuItems.

Thank you VGR for your comment